# Is there a way to handle this exception?

Tags: jwt, token, access-token

While implementing OAuth2.0 in our project. I have successfully generated a new access token. I have implemented this token in headers by enabling authorization. When I hit the API I get a response with the error message: The token was expected to have 3 parts, but got 4.

I tried to look out for a solution online but could find one. FYI, I am working in Java 1.8 and OAuth2.0.